# How do I stop Spyder from clearing variables instead of executing my PyQt script?

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

When I execute my PyQt script in Spyder, it doesn't seem to do anything except clearing variables. When I execute it again, it works as expected.

As you can see below, I cannot reduce the code any further, but the problem remains unchanged.
Is this the expected behaviour? What am I doing wrong?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

In detail:

1. I open Spyder.
2. I execute the script. A window opens and I terminate by closing the window (expected behaviour).
3. I execute the script. After a few seconds, the console returns. Nothing seems to have happened except that the variables are gone (unexpected behaviour).
4. Repeat from 2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't so much that the variables are being cleared, but rather that the PyQt application cannot be run repeatedly within Spyder. It's a common issue that is addressed in the Spyder Wiki: [How to run PyQt applications within Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-run-PyQt-applications-within-Spyder).

It seems to be tied to the fact that Spyder is itself a Qt application. Specifically, the Wiki entry has this by way of an explanation:

> The most common problem when running a PyQt application multiple times inside Spyder is that a QApplication instance remains in the namespace of the IPython console kernel after the first run. In other words, when you try to re-run your application, you already have a QApplication instance initialized.

The work-around is to make sure that the `QApplication` instance goes out of scope when your script exits, i.e., create it within the scope of a function. Using the simple example from above, it just comes down to this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

main()
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Also with this workaround, the application runs in the foreground automatically. Before, it started hidden beneath Spyder.